# Unused Lexical Variable

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Just started learning lisp. I have no idea why I am getting these errors or even what they mean. I am simply trying to code an approximation of pi using the Gregory-Leibniz series, here is the code.

```
(defun gl (n)
           (defparameter x 0)                        ;init variable to hold our runnning sum
           (loop for y from 0 to n                   ;number of iterations, starting from 0 to desired n
              (if (= y 0)                                      ;if n is 0 then we just want 4
                 (defparameter w 4))
              (if (> y 0)                                      ;else, 4*(-1^y)/((2 * y)+1)
                 (defparameter w (* 4 (/ (exp -1 y) (+ (* 2 y) 1)))))
              (+ x w))                                         ;add to our running sum
           (write x))                                        ;once loop is over, print x.
```

I have tried using setq, defvar, let etc. instead of defparameter but I still get "Undeclared free variable X".

I also get the error "Unused lexical variable N" even though I am using it for my loop, which is weird also.

How can I fix this and why is it happening? Thanks!

Comment: Don’t use `defparameter` inside `defun`. You should check the Hyperspec or some introduction book (see the info section for recommendations) for the idiomatic way to define local variables using `let` or inside `loop`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code after Emacs auto-indented it:

```
(defun gl (n)
  (defparameter x 0)
  (loop for y from 0 to n
       (if (= y 0)
           (defparameter w 4))
       (if (> y 0)
           (defparameter w (* 4 (/ (exp -1 y) (+ (* 2 y) 1)))))
       (+ x w))
  (write x))
```

Compiling the following code with SBCL gives one error and two warnings.

One warning says that `x` is undefined.
You should not call `defparameter` from inside your function, since [`defvar` and `defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) are used to declare dynamic variables and to set their value in the global scope. Prefer to have let bindings, or, since you already are using a loop, a `with` clause. When you want to modify a binding, use [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm).

The errors comes from the macroexpansion of `LOOP`, which is malformed. For SBCL, that means that the code is treated as dead-code for the rest of the function compilation; that explains why `n` appears not to be used, which is what the second warning is about.

There are various fixes remaining to be done:

- Use function `EXPT`, not `EXP`.
- Calling `(+ x w)` only computes a value but does not modify `x`, the result is useless.
- Prefer using `if` as expression, like a ternary operator in other languages, in your case the code can be simplified
- Adding one can be done with function `1+` (that's the name of the function, not a special syntax for adding constants)
- The `write` operation is rarely needed, especially if you are computing a mathematical formula; just return the value, and the REPL will print it automatically.

Small corrections that make your code works:

```
(defun gl (n)
  (let ((x 0))
    (loop
       for y from 0 to n
       for w = (if (= y 0)
                   4
                   (* 4 (/ (expt -1 y) (+ (* 2 y) 1))))
       do (setf x (+ x w)))
    (write x)))
```

I would personally get rid of `x` and `w`, and use a `SUM` loop clause.

```
(defun gl (n)
  (loop
     for y from 0 to n
     sum (if (zerop y)
             4
             (* 4 (/ (expt -1 y)
                     (1+ (* 2 y)))))))
```

Comment: Wow! I had no clue I was doing so many things wrong lol. I guess I'm used to the hand holding of python and c++. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Matt that's mostly a matter of how familiar you are with it, you'll probably catch up easily with CL, which is in some ways simpler than both C++ and Python (e.g. less corner cases).

Comment: Python hand-holding, you say? We can compile a `def foo(x): ... return y` in Python 3 without a warning that `x` is unused, or a warning that `y` is undefined. A `.pyc` file pops out that defines a nonworking compiled function.